# Python Tkimport how to make one from several windows when importing from a module?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, import

I am writing an application in tkinter consisting of several modules in which there are classes. Each module to a separate page of the app. As I move the buttons between the pages "next", "previous" it opens a new window for me every time. How do I make it so that each time calling pages opens in the same window?

I give draft code.

thank you for your help :D

task1.py

```
import tkinter as tk

from Test.modul.task1 import FirstPage1

class FirstPage0:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
    
    def get_settings(self):
        # Window settings
        self.root.geometry("100x200")
    
    def get_second_page(self):
        FirstPage1(tk.Toplevel()).get_run_first_page()
    
    def get_button(self):
        # Add buttons
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Start page", command=self.get_second_page).pack()
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.root.destroy).pack()
    
    def get_run_first_page(self):
        # Launching the application
        self.get_settings()
        self.get_button()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first = FirstPage0(tk.Tk())
    first.get_run_first_page()
```

task2.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class FirstPage1:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
    
    def get_settings(self):
        # Window settings
        self.root.geometry("100x200")
    
    def get_second_page1(self):
        from Test.task import FirstPage0
        FirstPage0(tk.Toplevel()).get_run_first_page()
    
    def get_button(self):
        # Add buttons
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Back", command=self.get_second_page1).pack()
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.root.destroy).pack()
    
    def get_run_first_page(self):
        # Launching the application
        self.get_settings()
        self.get_button()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first = FirstPage1(tk.Tk())
    first.get_run_first_page()
```

Comment: It should be `if __name__ == "__main__":` instead.

Comment: it's like this only the code removed highlights for me (autoformatting)

Comment: I fixed it manually :D

Comment: You need to use `self.root` instead of `tk.Toplevel()` when creating instance of page.

Comment: Sure thanks for the info but I have a question still how to make the displayed buttons not stack under each other but overwrite each other?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

@AdrianSz, you wanted to make the buttons not stack under each other. There are three ways to do so. One, is to keep only one button and change its `command` and `text` parameters each time when the frames change. Another would be to unpack the button not needed and pack the button needed. The third would be to pack the buttons in the root window instead of frame and change the `text` and `command` parameters. I would recommend the second method as it is easier and less prone to errors.

### Code

#### task1.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

from Test.modul.task1 import FirstPage1

class FirstPage0:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def get_settings(self):
        # Window settings
        self.root.geometry("100x200")

    def get_second_page(self):
        self.root.pg_0_btn_start.pack_forget()
        self.root_pg_0_btn_exit.pack_forget()
        FirstPage1(tk.Toplevel()).get_run_first_page()

    def get_button(self):
        # Add buttons

        self.root.pg_0_btn_start = tk.Button(self.root, text="Start page",                     
        command=self.get_second_page).pack()
        self.root_pg_0_btn_exit = tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", 
        command=self.root.destroy).pack()

    def get_run_first_page(self):
        # Launching the application
        self.get_settings()
        self.get_button()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first = FirstPage0(tk.Tk())
    first.get_run_first_page()
```

#### task2.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

class FirstPage1:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def get_settings(self):
        # Window settings
        self.root.geometry("100x200")

    def get_second_page1(self):
        from Test.task import FirstPage0
        self.root.pg_1_btn_back.pack_forget()
        self.root_pg_1_btn_exit.pack_forget()
        FirstPage0(tk.Toplevel()).get_run_first_page()

    def get_button(self):
        # Add buttons
        self.root.pg_1_btn_back = tk.Button(self.root, text="Back", command=self.get_second_page1).pack()
        self.root.pg_1_btn_exit = tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.root.destroy).pack()

    def get_run_first_page(self):
        # Launching the application
        self.get_settings()
        self.get_button()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first = FirstPage1(tk.Tk())
    first.get_run_first_page()
```

Note: I couldn't test this code from my side so if there are any errors, please comment on this answer

## Suggestions

Since you are using modules for these, just make them inherit a class specified in a different file and operate them both from that file. There you can use `self` to access the methods of a subclass because the subclasses instantiate the base class and thus the self is a object of the subclass and is passed to the base class. The type of code you used is quite confusing too. I have added code to give you your wanted output using the principles I mentioned here. Hope this helped!

Comment: root = root to write one script.

Comment: No, root refers to root window, see the edit.

Comment: I meant root= root.tk for all module. You don't need duplicated.

Comment: No, I mean that he can create a main app which imports both of the modules `task1.py` and `task2.py`.